# Set message header in rabbitmq while sending

Tags: jackson, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to set message header while sending a message to rabbit. 
I am using below code, but confused how to set message header in it.

```
public static <T> void sendMessage(String routingKey,final Object message,Class<T> type){
    DefaultClassMapper typeMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    typeMapper.setDefaultType(type);

    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    converter.setClassMapper(typeMapper);

    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(getConnectionFactory));
    template.setMessageConverter(converter);

    template.convertAndSend(routingKey, message);
}
```

In above method i am simply arguementing java POJO object and its type to send. I want to know where should i set message header here.

How to listen the message properties at listener end?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Java 8:

```
template.convertAndSend(routingKey, message, m -> {
    m.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put("foo", "bar");
    m.getMessageProperties().setPriority(priority);        
    return m;
});
```

Java 6,7:

```
template.convertAndSend(routingKey, message, new MessagePostProcessor() {

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message m) throws AmqpException {
        m.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put("foo", "bar");
        m.getMessageProperties().setPriority(priority);        
        return m;
    }

});
```

Comment: Don't put code in comments; as you can see, it's unreadable. Edit your question instead, and show all your configuration. Priority is a message property, not a message header. Use `m.getMessageProperties().setPriority(priority)`.

Comment: It's not necessary to call `getHeaders()` first. Could simplify to `m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("foo", "bar");`